# Phonegap push notification sort of (fire event from remote)

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm looking for a way to trigger a phonegap app to do something by sending a notification from server. I am okay if it sends an actual notification but I also want it to fire some kind of event that my app can listen to - in my case I need the app to a) receive a notice of new messages and automatically reload the messages from server - or at least set a flag to reload once the user relaunches app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Google Groups post shows how to call a javascript method from the delegate file

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/easyapns/5vGAEDSRQDY

Answer (score 0):

[Urban Airship has a demo](https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/66970-implementing-with-phonegap) that might be worth checking.

Hope this helps!

Note that I am no way affiliated with this product or it's authors.

Comment: Thanks - I did look at their stuff - just trying to find simple notes in how to call javascript from delegate which I did locate.